# Can Angular 2 use property-binding on a :before or :after element?

Tags: css, angular, property-binding

I am templating a page and need to bind to the border-color property of a div's css :before element. Is this possible in Angular 2?

I know I could write some css and use class binding to toggle the color, but this requires all possible colors to be known beforehand so it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: I can't imagine how this could work. The only thing is `ngStyle` and I don't see how this could be applied to a before or after element.

Comment: After a good cup of coffee I came up with a workaround for my case at least: I'll bind to the parent element's border-color and set the :before border-color to `inherit`.

Comment: try currentColor property in css

Comment: @L.V. you save my day. You comment should be the answer...